# Comparing Variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I am looking for a method of comparing two string variables in VBA. The current statement I am using (which is not producing the desired result) is:

- `If Variable1 = Variable2 Then...`

I have a VBA macro that assigns two variables in the first part of my code:

- `Dim Variable1 as String Variable1 = Left(Range("$F$3").Value, 4)`
- `Dim Variable2 as String Variable2 = ("SheetName.B15")`

I have tried using the following statement, but it still does not work correctly:

- `If Variable1 Like Variable2 Then...`

Previously, the statement was working with a string comparison to the first variable, but it required that I hard-coded the "ABC" string. It looked like the below statement:

- `If Variable1 = "ABC" Then...`

Does anybody know the syntax of a statement to compare two string variables, or could recommend a method for comparing them in a sub and return a binary result, which I could then compare?

Thanks!

---

Running VBA for Excel 2013 on Windows 8

Comment: If you `Debug.Print` the value of each variable what do you see?

Comment: @Tim-Williams 

Great advice, `Debug.Print` shows that I was incorrectly assigning Variable2. Variable2 came back as `"SheetName.B15"`.

Using that information, I corrected my variable assignment to:
`Dim Variable2 As String Variable2 = Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(15,"B").Value`

Thanks for the push!

Comment: [like this](http://www.databison.com/index.php/string-comparison-function-in-vba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

I wasn't correctly assigning Variable2 and therefore, the function wasn't producing the desired result. Thanks everyone for their contributions, through the reply's - here's what we've come up with:

To compare two string variables in an existing sub, use:

```
If Variable1 = Variable 2 Then...
```

To compare two string variable in it's own sub, use:

```
Sub compare()
    MsgBox StrComp("Stack", "stack") 'alerts -1 
End Sub

Sub compare()
    MsgBox StrComp("Stack", "stack", 1) 'Compare as text while ignoring case
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StrComp`

```
 Sub compare()
        MsgBox StrComp("Stack", "stack") 'alerts -1 
    End Sub

Sub compare()
    MsgBox StrComp("Stack", "stack", 1) 'Compare as text while ignoring case
End Sub
```

The first one is case sensitive where the 2nd is not, of course you can replace the hardcoded values with variables

Comment: Thanks for providing this. It is a good method for comparing string variable in a sub.

Alternatively, I was able to achieve this without having to code a new sub by using `If Variable1 = Variable2 Then`...I wasn't correctly assigning Variable2 in my test pass.